# ImageView radius with background

Tags: android, imageview

I have an `ImageView` that has a background. I need to set `border-radius` to my `ImageView`. I use the below code in another XML file and set it as `android:src` but it doesn't work when I set the background.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

How I can set background and radius at the same time ?

Comment: as you are using android:src so you have to provide radius to bitmap when setting as imageview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the background together with the border-radius xml.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
   <!-- background -->
   <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Comment: I dont need BackgroundColor. I need my picture to be background.